# Python - Instantiate object from SQLite cursor

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm running into an error when I try to instantiate an object from a cursor in SQLite and I've exhausted my research and couldn't find a solution.

Premise: I cannot use SqlAlchemy or anything of that sorts.

Assumption: The database (SQLite) works, it contains a table named table_cars, and the table is populated with data in its single column: name.

So, I have a class lets say:

```
class Car():
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name

   @classmethod
      def from_cursor(cls, c):
         car = cls(c(0))
         # this line breaks when called from the function below.
```

And I also have a db module, with the following function:

```
def get_cars_from_db():
   sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_cars;'
   conn = get_conn()
   cur = conn.cursor()
   cur.execute(sql)
   data = cur.fetchall()
   # at this point, if i print the cursor, I can see all data, so far so good.

   cars = [Car.from_cursor(c) for c in data]
   # the line above causes the code to break

   return cars
```

The code breaks with the following error:

`TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In list comprehension of `get_cars_from_db()`, `c` is a row of the db select result. In `from_cursor()` you are using `c(0)` which means `c` is callable and you are calling it with parameter 0

Comment: so how do I extract the data from the cursor to parse it into the object?

Comment: In `from_cursor()`, `c` is a tuple with same number of entries as column in your `table_cars`. You can fetch the name from that tuple and then create Car object

Comment: now I realise that I need to use [] to access an index of a tuple, not (). Silly me.
so the correct syntax would be ```car = cls(c[0])```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cls(c[0])` or `cls(*c)` to unpack tuple to function arguments.
It's also worth to specify an exact order of your columns in query.

```
select name from table_cars
```